# Printing PDF file using PrintDocument but keeeping ActualSize

Tags: c#, printing, settings, printdocument

In my c# program there is a section that prints picktickets using Crystal reports.  The report saves the data as a pdf.  there is a reason why it needs to go to PDF and not just print straight to a printer.

I want to be sure that when printdocument executes it does not perform a fit to page.  I did look around and even asked LLM, but nothing was clear.  When I look at a print settings screen I can see an option 'Actual Size' and when I switch between that and 'fit to printable area' I can see the page change size in preview.

[image: Printer settings]

It is that line marked in yellow I want to emulate when calling print document.

```
            PrinterSettings printerSettings = new PrinterSettings();
        System.Drawing.Printing.PageSettings pageSettings = new System.Drawing.Printing.PageSettings(printerSettings);

        printerSettings.PrinterName = toPrinter;
        printerSettings.Duplex = Duplex.Simplex;
        //printerSettings.FromPage = 1;
        //printerSettings.ToPage = 3;

        PaperSource ps = new PaperSource();
        ps.RawKind = (int)PaperSourceKind.Middle;
        printerSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSource = ps;
        

        PrintDocument printDocument = document.CreatePrintDocument();
        printDocument.PrinterSettings = printerSettings;
        printDocument.PrintController = new StandardPrintController();
        PrintingPermission perm = new PrintingPermission(System.Security.Permissions.PermissionState.Unrestricted);
        perm.Level = PrintingPermissionLevel.AllPrinting;
        // Something here to set "Actual Size"

        // The Big MOMENT!!!

        printDocument.Print();
```